# Query returns an object instead of Array

Tags: laravel

I have written a model function which has to give me all the posts with user's id, but it returns a model object instead.
My model:

```
public static function my_posts(){

    $userId = Auth::id();
    $getPosts = DB::table('posts')->where('user_id',$userId)->get();
    return $getPosts;
}
```

My Controller function:

```
public function myPosts(){
        $getPosts = new posts_model();
        $getPosts->my_posts();
        return view("myposts",["posts" => $getPosts]);
    }
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: This is what I get when I do a dd($posts) in my view: posts_model {#239 ▼
  #table: "posts"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  +incrementing: true
  #connection: null
  #keyType: "int"
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please change Model

```
public static function my_posts(){
    $userId = Auth::id();
    $getPosts = Post::where('user_id',$userId)->get();
    return $getPosts;
}
```

Then Change Your controller

```
public function myPosts(){
    $getPosts = new posts_model();
    $data = $getPosts->my_posts();
    return view("myposts", ["posts" => $data]);
}
```